# How to adjust the position of regression equation on ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, equation, lm

I would like to add the regression line and R^2 to my ggplot. I am fitting the regression line to different categories and for each category I am getting a unique equation. I'd like to set the position of equations for each category manually. i.e. Finding the max expression of y for each group and printing the equation at ymax + 1.

Here is my code:

```
library(ggpmisc)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:100))
df$y <- 20 * c(0, 1) + 3 * df$x + rnorm(100, sd = 40)
df$group <- factor(rep(c("A", "B"), 50))
df <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(ymax = max(y))
my.formula <- y ~ x
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   do(tidy(lm(y ~ x, data = .))) 

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = group)) +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, formula = my.formula) +
   stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula, 
             aes(x = x , y = ymax + 1, label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")),
              parse = TRUE) +         
   geom_point()
p
```

Any suggestion how to do this?

Also is there any way I can only print the slope of the equation. (remove the intercept from plot)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that setting adjusting `stat_poly_eq()` with the `geom` argument will get what you want. Doing so will center the equations, leaving the left half of each clipped, so we use `hjust = 0` to left-adjust the equations.  Finally, depending on your specific data, the equations may be overlapping each other, so we use the `position` argument to have ggplot attempt to separate them.

This adjusted call should get you started, I hope:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = group)) +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, formula = my.formula) +
   stat_poly_eq(
      formula = my.formula, 
      geom = "text",  # or 'label'
      hjust = 0,  # left-adjust equations
      position = position_dodge(),  # in case equations now overlap
      aes(x = x , y = ymax + 1, label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")),
      parse = TRUE) +         
   geom_point()
p
```